# Adding audio to click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to add a sound clip to a button on a game I am creating. Currently It doesn't do anything and I don't know why.

At the moment In the script I have...

```
var audio = $(".mysoundclip")[0];
$(".minibutton").onclick(function() {
    audio.play();
});
```

In the HTML I have...

```
<audio id="mysoundclip" preload="auto">
    <source src="http://www.wav-sounds.com/cartoon/bugsbunny1.wav"></source>
</audio>
```

Then I have CSS for .minibutton.

Any ideas why it won't work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your jQuery had some simple errors in it.

HTML

```
<audio id="mysoundclip" preload="auto">
    <source src="http://www.wav-sounds.com/cartoon/bugsbunny1.wav"></source>
</audio>
<button type="button">play</button>
```

jQuery

```
var audio = $("#mysoundclip")[0];
$("button").click(function() {
    audio.play();
});​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/VavyK/

​

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm a too suspicous.. but

`http://www.sound-effect.com/sounds1/animal/Saf/Tiger1.wav` "The requested URL was not found on this server"

If that's just a typo, you should also try to figure out which audio types a browser is capable to play:

```
myApp.htmlAudio = (function _htmlAudioCheck() {
    var elem = document.createElement('audio'),
        bool = false;

    try {
        if( !!elem.canPlayType ) {
            bool = new Boolean(bool);
            bool.ogg = elem.canPlayType('audio/ogg; codecs="vorbis"');
            bool.mp3 = elem.canPlayType('audio/mpeg;');

            bool.wav = elem.canPlayType('audio/wav; codecs="1"');
            bool.m4a = ( elem.canPlayType('audio/x-m4a;') ||      elem.canPlayType('audio/aac;'));
        }
    } catch(e) { }

    return bool;
}());
```

Now we can check like

```
if( myApp.htmlAudio && myApp.htmlAudio.wav ) {
}
```

if the browser is able to playback `.wav` files for instance.

However, I never saw a nested `source element` for `audio elements`. That should be named `track` if anything. But you don't really need that here, you can just have a `src` attribute on the `audio element` itself. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/5GUPg/1/

Comment: Do you know any good sites to get legitimate sounds from? @jAndy

Comment: I'm afraid, I don't know that, sorry.

Comment: I need wav, I have already checked browser compatibility. Thanks.

Comment: So now I have a working sound. Have any ideas why it isn't working? @jAndy

Comment: @IronSpoon: yes, you should have the `src` attribute directly on the `audio element`, no need for nested `sourced elements`. For instance: http://jsfiddle.net/5GUPg/

Comment: I want it to play on click though not automatically @jAndy